# How to setup error 404 page in Ruby on Rails system testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

Rails 5.1 introduced [system testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#implementing-a-system-test) that uses Capybara with Selenium to test the UI of Rails application.

I'm wondering to how to use this system testing to test the UI of error pages.

For standard controller tests, we can do something like below to assert response to be 404.

```
test 'should get not_found' do
  get errors_not_found_url
  assert_response :not_found
end
```

But for system tests, if I go to a 404 page, exception will be thrown in controller level and tests terminate immediately without rendering the page.

```
test '404 page should render with the correct title' do
  # act.
  visit NOT_FOUND_URL

  # assert.
  assert_equal("#{APP_NAME} - #{TITLE_404}", page.title)
end
```

Exception is thrown in controller level.

```
$ rails test test/system/error/error_page_test.rb
Run options: --seed 30076

# Running:

Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 1
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:55237
Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-07-09 11:10:45 +1200: Rack app error handling request { GET /books/12345678 }
#<ActionController::RoutingError: Could not find book '12345678' by id or name>
/myapp/app/controllers/books_controller.rb:7:in `index'
/Users/yze14/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.2/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/yze14/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
...
```

Under development/test environment, `config.consider_all_requests_local` can be set to `false` in order to show error page instead of stracktrace. But this doesn't swallow exception during system tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Capybara to re-raise server exceptions in the tests you can set `Capybara.raise_server_errors = false`.

Secondly, you should check your Gemfile and make sure any gems like `web-console`,`better-errrors`, etc are only loaded in the development environment (not in the test environment)

Finally, you shouldn't be using `assert_equal` with `title`, you should be using the Capybara provided `assert_title` which includes waiting/retrying behavior and will reduce potential flakiness in tests.

```
assert_title("#{APP_NAME} - #{TITLE_404}")
```

Comment: Thanks! Just checking how to use `Capybara.raise_server_errors = false` in `test/application_system_test_case.rb`? I'm using `poltergeist` driver.

Comment: @YiZeng . You can set it  in any of your test setup files, however you probably want to leave it as `true` for most tests so you find out about errors raised by your app - so setting to false in a setup block for tests that check your error pages, and resetting to true in a teardown probably makes the most sense.

Comment: This seems to be working with Capybara side of things where it ignores such application error. But as to Rails system testing, the page still shows "An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details." instead of rendering an actual error page.

Comment: @YiZeng That's pumas default unhandled error message - it sounds like you don't have any code producing a custom error message page.